# Change SVG Fill color in React JS

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

Consider:

```
import LOGO from './something.svg';
<img src={LOGO} className={'logo'} alt="Logo"/> //
```

How can I change fill color of SVG in ReactJS ?

I've tried also to use ReactComponent but I got `'ReactComponent' is not exported from ....`

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo1 } from './something.svg';
<Logo1 /> // doesn't work : 'ReactComponent' is not exported from ....
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @SergiiShvager : Don't know , how can I check ?

Comment: do you export the component? looks like you don't in the code

Comment: Do you have react-scripts in dependencies(package.json) ?

Comment: @SergiiShvager : No , I don't.

Comment: import { ReactComponent } from 'file.svg' works only with create-react-app or @svgr/webpack loader. By default it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to import react in the component but to change the fill color the svg has to be called as a component rather than making it as `src` for `img` tag.

For eg, if you have an svg file, make it a React component like:

```
import React from 'react';

const Icon = ({fill, className }) => (
  <svg className={className} version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="umbrella" viewBox="0 0 596 597">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <desc>Umbrella icon</desc>
    <path fill={fill} class="shaft" d="M260.4,335.7 L260.4,478 C260.4,543.1 313.4,596.1 378.5,596.1 C443.6,596.1 496.6,543.1 496.6,478 C496.6,457.5 479.9,440.8 459.4,440.8 C438.9,440.8 422.2,457.5 422.2,478 C422.2,502.2 402.7,521.7 378.5,521.7 C354.3,521.7 334.8,502.2 334.8,478 L334.8,335.7 L260.4,335.7 L260.4,335.7 Z"></path>
    <path class="fabric" d="M558,335.7 C578.5,335.7 595.2,319 595.2,298.5 L595.2,294.8 C593.4,132 460.4,0.9 297.6,0.9 L297.6,0.9 C133.9,0.9 0,134.8 0,298.5 C0,319 16.7,335.7 37.2,335.7 L558,335.7 L558,335.7 Z M77.2,261.3 C94.9,156.2 187,75.3 297.6,75.3 C408.2,75.3 500.4,156.2 518,261.3 L77.2,261.3 L77.2,261.3 Z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
);

export default Icon;
```

And call the Icon in your component with `fill`.

```
<Icon fill="#ffffff" className="myclass" />
```

An alternate solution will be to pass a className like fill prop and use that class name in CSS to change the color, like:

```
.myclass path {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I need to use the SVG's filename , by path , not by its injected code.Thanks.

Comment: @JAN As Joe Lloyd said, you have to use the raw svg, to edit the fill

Answer (score 4):

In your jsx:

`import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './something.svg';`

`const MyComponent = () => <Logo className="logo" />`

in your css:

```
.logo > path {
   fill: "white"
}
```

This should work just fine

Comment: Why are you doing that second step with the const assignment and arrow function?

Once you've imported the SVG using the first line of this answer, just use the component in your code:
<Logo className="logo" />

Answer (score 2):

You can use webpack loader that will transform SVG into react component and there you can add className to change fill or directly pass prop fill to svg react component.

SVGR is an awesome tool that converts your SVG into React components that you can use. So how do we set it up?

First, we install the package $ npm install @svgr/webpack --save-dev.

Then we update our Webpack configuration rule to use SVGR for SVGs:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  //...
};
```

Now we can import our SVG images as a React component and use it in our code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactLogo from './logo.svg';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactLogo fill="white" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What do I do with the first piece of code `const webpack = require('webpack'); ....` ? What's the name of this component ?

Comment: That's usually webpack.config.js file

Comment: If it is not used anywhere in your config then just remove it ;)

Comment: Where do I put this file ? how does the React project knows about its existence ?

Comment: I think you should have already webpack config. Webpack is bundling your project and adds plugins to your code (like this svg one). Search for webpack.config.js

Comment: Or to simplify things you should do you can create react component from SVG yourself, so you don't need any plugins. Just paste content of SVG here and create new js file then you don't need to touch any webpack magic at all. https://react-svgr.com/playground/

Comment: Solution with fill attribute inside svg component for me doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

## Export component

```
import React from 'react';
import LOGO from './something.svg';

const Logo = () => <img src={LOGO} className={'logo'} alt="Logo"/>;
export default Logo;
```

to import this component you should use

`import Logo from 'path/to/react/logo/component';`

## Make sure you have a svg handler in your build process

Webpack doesn't know what to do with svg files by default so it will cause a build time fail. You need to add a plugin or loader to it. Or use something like Next.js or Gatsby that have built in webpack setups.

## Fill colour

As for using a fill colour, its not possible when you use an image tag to set your svg in an image tag. You must use the raw svg in your app, that way you can edit the fill.

Comment: But where do you change the fill color ?

Comment: Nice question @JAN

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke you cant change the color with an image tag. you need to load an svg directly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in react-native. If you have the svg file, you can use it in a function component like this.

for ex.

```
import React from 'react';  
import {Svg, Path} from 'react-native-svg';

const Icon = ({fill = 'white', height, width}) => ( 
  <Svg height={height} width={width} viewBox="0 0 15 15">    
    <Path d="xxx xxx xxx" fill={fill} />
  </Svg> 
);
```

Then import this component and pass the desired fill prop value

Hope this work for you too.